# MS Access just stopped recognizing it's own text box exists

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

An MS Access form that has been working for over a year now, does a simple:

"Dim MyQuoteID as INTEGER

MyQuoteID = Me.QuoteID"

(It then proceeds to execute an SQL Statement inserting "MyQuoteID" that it just captured from the form)

...Only now it errors and says "Method or data member not found" on "Me.QuoteID".

Of course, the "QuoteID" box is right there, plainly visible, and has been for over a year.

Obviously some kind of corruption because I didn't change anything - but it doesn't solve with a compact and repair!

WTH??????

Comment: `INT` is not a native VBA datatype.  Is that just a typo from translating your code (and it's actually dimmed as an `Integer`) or do you have a custom class/type of `INT` that you have defined within your project?

Comment: No, it is correctly integer and defined as such in my code. I should not have shortened it to "INT" in my question here.

Comment: Have you tried either of my suggestions?

Comment: Does `MyQuoteID = Me!QuoteID` work?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try:

1. Decompile via the command line (`msaccess.exe "path\to\your.mdb" /decompile`)
2. Use the undocumented `SaveAsText` and `LoadFromText` methods to "export" and "import" your form

   1. `SaveAsText acForm, "YourFormName", "YourFormName.txt"`
   2. `LoadFromText acForm, "YourFormName", "YourFormName.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write TextBox rather than INT. Assuming that this code is in the VBA module for a form, you do not need to define any of the controls in this way, nor is it good practice to do so. Just delete these two lines, and it might fix your problem.

Comment: If it's been working for over a year, it's what the OP meant. He's apparently depending on the text box's default `Value` property--which could lead to other problems, but wouldn't throw the error he's reporting.

Comment: Actually, I would guess the OP meant to write `Integer` and that his next line of code makes use of the textbox's default `.Value` property.  In which case I'd argue it *is* good practice to put the value of a control in a native datatype if you will be performing integer types of operations against that value.